# 2D annulus plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to create an annular plot of a function z=f(x,y), such as

http://www.gibmetportal.gi/images/example_polar_annulus_plot.jpg

in MATLAB. My data (x,y,z=f(x,y)) is in a csv file, which I can read in MATLAB. The problem is that x and y are not given as a regular grid, i.e., they do not resemble the output of the `meshgrid` command. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're problem is that the data is scattered and not on a regular grid?

try doc griddata

Comment: Cool, thanks! I ended up using `scatteredInterpolant`, as I needed to interpolate a few different outputs on the same scattered data, but the idea was there. Bit of advice for anyone that tries to do this: you need to remove duplicate points in your scattered data first!